# From and return-path in PHP mail header not working

Tags: php, server

I have a form with simple structure, that the user will be able to send mails to me through it. My code so far has been working, but the problem is if I change the header to appear the email user and not mine, it doesn't work.

My code :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $to = 'noreply@example.com'; //email that will be sent the message
        $subject = 'Mail';

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email_sender = $_POST['email'];
        $message= $_POST['message'];
        $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: noreply@example.com\r\n";
        $header.= "Return-Path: noreply@example.com\r\n";

        $envio = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

        if($envio) {
            header('Location: http://website.com');
        }
        else {
            header('Location: /index.html#contact');
        }
    }
?>
```

If I change the headers in "From" and "Return-Path", to the follow :

```
$headers .= "From:" .$email_sender. "\r\n";
$headers.= "Return-Path:" .$email_sender. "\r\n";
```

It doesn't send anymore the emails. What is the problem happening here?

Comment: One is `$headers`, one is `$header`.

Comment: It was just a typo in here. But changing it, still doesn't work.